# virtual directory site not using new database in DNN

Tags: dotnetnuke

I created a virtual directory for my dnn site which uses new database steps are as follows
right click on site -> add virtual directory 
copied all file from dnn site to virtual directory folder
runs the site it woks file
create backup of old sql database (which are used by dnn site) 
create new database in sql and restore old database backup on it
changed the connection string of web.config file
runs the site but its not using new database (using old database)

I want to know what changes  I need to do my virtual directory so that it uses new database please guide me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are running it in a sub-directory or new virtual directory make sure your PortalAlias table in your SQL database has the proper URL in it.  There are two spots in your web.config file that the database needs to be changed. That is the *only* place that your database connections will be.  Recycle your application pool / restart IIS / restart your DNN application in the HOST menu just to make sure it is all cleared up and it is referencing your  web.config file (even though just saving the web.config with different info should have been sufficient)

But the web.config file is the only place the database connections would be, if you have a web.config file higher up (above your virtual directory) it could be affecting your web.config in a sub directory.

Comment: thanks for your reply. yes i have a web.config file higher up and it is affecting in a subdirectory. ant I have changed the portal alias table url for new database but nothing happen........how can i resolve this issue please guide me

Comment: I wouldn't try and run DNN in a directory within another .NET project / under another web.config.  In ISS you can make a directory and put a virtual directory under it and have DNN run in that directory. But if you have another web.config DNN will inherit from that config and you're going to have a bad day.